# How to return a promise resolved from a callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have an issue with my promise logic (still pretty new to JS), and I cannot find what is wrong.
Looking at how hard it is for me to do what I want, I can only guess that's it's not the correct way to do it. I did found another way to fix it, but I am still interested if there is a way to do what I want or not.

Here are some details:

I have a `MessageQueue.sendMessage()` which adds the message I give to the `PendingMessageCache`. When it can, the `MessageQueue` takes the cache and sends the `Message` to the server.

Sometimes I need to do some stuff after the message is sent. So I added a `callback`, saved and invoked by the `MessageQueue` when it sends the message. It's working great. The call looks basically like this:

```
await MessageQueue.sendMessage(myMsg, () => {markMessageAsSent()});
```

For one new type of message, I need to wait for the message being effectively sent because the app is completely cleaned after it.

As the  `sendMessage` just adds the message to the `cache` and returns, the `callback` is later called but **in this case it's too late**, the app was restarted.

The message is basically a `lastMessage` sent to the server to say that this user removed the specific application instance.

So I think that what I want would be something like this:

```
deleteAccount = async () => {
    const aMagicalCallback;

    // this call adds the message to the cache, 
    // and ask the MessageQueue to call aMagicalCallback when that lastMsg is sent
    await MessageQueue.sendLastMessage(lastMsg, <aMagicalCallback>);
    // return the callback which would be a promise.
    // this promise is resolved when it is resolved 
    // when the MessageQueue invokes the callback <aMagicalCallback>
    return <aMagicalCallback>;
}
```

what I would like this to do is basically

```
    // wait for the lastMessageBeingEffectively sent
    await deleteAccount();
    app.eraseEverything();
    app.restart();
```

Let me know if that is not clear at all.
And thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of using `async`. So you can choose when to resolve the promise, even in a nested callback function:

```js
deleteAccount = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    MessageQueue.sendLastMessage(lastMsg, () => {
        // do your thing
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Then you can await it just like a regular `async` function

```js
// this awaits until the resolve() above has been called
await deleteAccount();

app.eraseEverything();
app.restart();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're already adding a callback function to every message. Instead of thinking of a separate callback to be injected after the promise is created, you could have the original callback check for the size of the message queue and execute

```
app.eraseEverything();
app.restart();
```

when it's empty.